# Wordpress display pop up on admin page when admin click on "update the post"

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, popup

Everything is in the title. I already know that I have to use [the wordpress plugin API action reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post) but I don't know how to do to display a pop up on the admin page from this plugin. My plugin code :

```
<?php
add_action( 'save_post', 'salle_number' );
function salle_number($post_id) {
          //display a popup
        ?> 
          <script>
          alert('I am a pop-up alert');
          </script>
        <?php
  }  
?>
```

Any idea?

Comment: Didn't try anything? Not even codes?

Comment: @Raptor I create a plugin whith a function which is called when the user click on "update post".

Comment: Post your codes please

Comment: What's the real issue? Why do you need this popup?

Comment: @brasofilo I want that popup because what I want to do is when the admin click on update post, I check the value of some custom field, and if it's not the good value, I will display a popup to the admin

Comment: what is the error / warning ?

Comment: There is no error/warning from my plugin. It is activate. When I click on 'update post' nothing appears. I open the console in my browser to see if something happens when I click on "update post" but nothing.

Comment: @Raptor this is supposed to work what I have write in my post? No?

Comment: Any error in Developer Console? use `console.log` to debug.

Comment: @Raptor I put a 'console.log("toto")' inside the script tag, and when I click on update post nothing is display in the browser console. So my plugin may not be called... but why...

Comment: Did you **activate** your plugin ?

Comment: @Raptor Yes I try to desactivate and activate, same result.

Comment: @Raptor maybe I don't have the plugin api "save_post"/action reference...

Comment: what do you mean by don't have the Plugin API "save_post" ?

Answer (score 0):

Since popup you mentioned is a client-side (browser-side) effects, you have to work it out in client-side scripts, most probably via JavaScript.

Therefore, you can run the following script:

```
<script>
alert('I am a pop-up alert');
</script>
```

in your else branch.

Comment: I try this : <?php
add_action( 'save_post', 'salle_number' );
function salle_number() {
  ?> 
   <script>
   alert('I am a pop-up alert');
   </script>
  <?php
}

?>   but it doesn't work

Comment: update your question please. doesn't work is not a valid issue description